# ¿Por qué Webpack no me compila el style de vuejs y el resto del componente si?

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, vue.js, webpack

Tengo un problema a la hora de compilar este componente de VueJS:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="container" id="contentWrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 mt-5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4>Let's Chat</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body" id="chat" style="height: 400px;"></div>
          <form class="card-footer" id="message-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}

  $(function() {

    //Socket conectado
    const socket = io();

    //Obteniendo los elementos del dom desde la interfaz
    const $messageForm = $('#message-form');
    const $messageBox = $('#message');
    const $chat = $('#chat');
    const $send = $("#enviar");

    //Eventos
    ///Esto lo que hace es evitar que se recargue la pagina cada vez que se envia el formulario
    $messageForm.submit( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
      $messageBox.val('');
    });

    //Escuchar el evento que viene desde el servidor

      socket.on('new message', function(data) {
        if(data === "") return false;

        $chat.append(`${data} <br />`);
      });
  });

</script>

<style>
#contentWrap {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

me lo compila solo si le quito la etiqueta Style, si se la dejo me sale esto:

> ERROR in ./src/app/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
>   (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/app/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
>   58:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (58:0) You may need
>   an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | |
>
> > ## contentWrap { |   display: none; | }  @ ./src/app/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 1:0-126 1:142-145
> >
> > 1:147-270 1:147-270  @ ./src/app/App.vue  @ ./src/app/main.js

Creo que tiene que ver con la configuracion de webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/main.js',
  output : {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src/public/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use:'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Que has intentado hacer?,te sugiero leer este articulo : sindominio.net/ayuda/preguntas-inteligentes.html de como hacer buenas preguntas , porque te lo aseguro esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con stackoverflow, te sugiero buscar en google :) y si no sabes como se crean las buenas preguntas aqui, te recomiendo leer el tour : es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Mi pregunta es por qué el Webpack no me compila los estilos que coloco en el componentn de Vuejs. Ahí está el código de webpack y el componente que he intentado, si no sabes pues está bien, esperaré a otro que me ayude.

Comment: Romer : mira esta linea : -> 58:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (58:0) posiblemente tienes  agregado un "#"

Comment: @simon pero si le quito el selector como sabe el style si me refiero a un id o a una clase?